# How to lock docker's config.json file?

Tags: windows, docker

I am working on windows and everytime docker restarts it modifies the config.json by adding the below. It's not a big deal, but I wish I could tell docker to prompt user before editing it (slightly less annoying) or better just stop updating the file. Is there a way to instruct docker to not modify configs upon restart?

Format I manually reset it to get builds to work:
{"auths":{"some-resource":{"auth":"some-encoding"}},"credStore":"desktop"}

Upon restart it adds:
,"credsStore":"desktop"